# Prove that $n\sum_{i=1}^n(a_{i-1}a_{i+1})^{(n-1)/2}\le\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i^n(a_{i+1}+a_{i-1})}{a_{i+1}^n+a_{i-1}^n}$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Given odd integer $n$ greater than one and $n$ positives $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n - 1}, a_n$, prove that $$n \cdot \frac{(a_na_2)^{(n - 1)/2} + (a_1a_3)^{(n - 1)/2} + \cdots + (a_{n - 2}a_n)^{(n - 1)/2} + (a_{n - 1}a_1)^{(n - 1)/2}}{a_1^{n - 2} + a_2^{n - 2} + \cdots + a_{n - 1}^{n - 2} + a_n^{n - 2}}$$$$ \le \frac{a_1^n}{a_n^{n - 1} - a_n^{n - 2}a_1 + \cdots - a_na_1^{n - 2} + a_1^{n - 1}} + \frac{a_2^n}{a_1^{n - 1} - a_1^{n - 2}a_3 + \cdots - a_1a_3^{n - 2} + a_3^n}$$$$ + \cdots + \frac{a_{n - 1}^n}{a_{n - 2}^{n - 1} - a_{n - 2}^{n - 2}a_n + \cdots - a_{n - 2}a_n^{n - 2} + a_n^{n - 1}} + \frac{a_n^n}{a_{n - 1}^{n - 1} - a_{n - 1}^{n - 2}a_1 + \cdots - a_{n - 1}a_1^{n - 2} + a_1^n}$$

(Essentially, $$n \cdot \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n(a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1})^{(n - 1)/2}}{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^na_i^{n - 2}} \le \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{a_i^n(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n},$$ where $a_0 = a_p$ and $a_{p + 1} = a_1$.)

According to the Cauchy - Schwarz inequality, $$\left[\sum_{i = 1}^na_i^{(n + 1)/2}\right]^2 = \left[\sum_{i = 1}^n\sqrt{\frac{a_i(a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n)}{a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1}}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{a_i^n(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n}}\right]^2$$

$$\le \left[\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{a_i(a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n)}{a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1}}\right] \cdot \left[\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{a_i^n(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n}\right]$$

We now need to prove that $$n \cdot \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n(a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1})^{(n - 1)/2}}{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^na_i^{n - 2}} \le \frac{\displaystyle \left[\sum_{i = 1}^na_i^{(n + 1)/2}\right]^2}{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{a_i(a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n)}{a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1}}}$$

$$\iff n \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n(a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1})^{(n - 1)/2} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{a_i(a_{i + 1}^n + a_{i - 1}^n)}{a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1}} \le \sum_{i = 1}^na_i^{n - 2} \cdot \left[\sum_{i = 1}^na_i^{(n + 1)/2}\right]^2$$

And this is where I'm stuck, of course, there were a few more ideas, such as implementing Schur's inequality, $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}a_i^{n - 1}(a_i - a_{i + 1})(a_i - a_{i - 1}) \ge 0, i = \overline{1, n}, a_0 = a_n, a_{n + 1} = a_i,$$ but that's all that I can think of.